# Prevent get_valid_filename() from changing the filename of a file

Tags: django, file

I am migrating to Django a site that has a large set of files that are already uploaded on AWS.

Some of these files have special characters or blank spaces, that Django overwrites, which then makes the files not available.

Example (original_name > django_name):

```
unnamed (19).jpg > unnamed%20(19).jpg
```

I have tried to use a custom storage backend with:

```
class MyFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        return name
```

and in my models:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/, max_length=255, storage=MyFileStorage())
```

but it doesn't help, the files with special characters are still renamed by django.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Django rename spaces with underscores ( " " -> "_")

Comment: moreover, by defining a custom storage class, it won't rename the files which are already in aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comments it was not the function I had in mind which was replacing the spaces by %20, this wad done by the `url()` function from `FileSystemStorage`, so this is how I managed to make it work:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin    
class MyFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):
        def url(self, name):
            url = name
            return urljoin(self.base_url, url)
```